# Casting to class using a class name

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to cast to a class type by string value.

```
    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        Class class = [self class];
        NSString *className = NSStringFromClass(class);

        NSArray* nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:className owner:self options:NULL];
        NSEnumerator* nibEnumerator = [nibContents objectEnumerator];
        NSObject* nibObject = nil;
        while ((nibObject = [nibEnumerator nextObject]) != nil) {
            if ([nibObject isKindOfClass:class]) {
                self = nibObject; // <<< compiler warning
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return self;
}
```

This code is part of a UITableViewCell superclass. I have a whole bunch of UITableViewCell subclasses that all wants to load their own nibs using the above snippet. This is working really well but I have a compiler warning on the line  self = nibObject.

I would like to suppress the compiler warning but that would require casting, along the lines of

```
self = (className *)nibObject;
```

So how can I do this in my super class so I don't have to essentially repeat the above snippet in every subclass and cast per usual?

Comment: Your compiler is warning you that nibContents might be null. Don't reassign nil

Comment: You can't cast to a runtime value, since casting is compile-time; the solution is probably, as posted below, to cast to `id`.  Also, unless you have a specific reason to use `NSEnumerator`, you're probably better off using fast enumeration (a `for`-`in` loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are completely sure that classes are compatible, then cast it as `id`:

```
self = (id)nibObject;
```

(self is returned as `id` as well)

Comment: Worth noting that objective-c class-casts are just no-ops and are there to prevent you from doing a mistake. Messages are always sent dynamically through object's `isa` field and never depend on variable's declared "class".